# C++ :: Как передать строку, разбив по разделителям, в массив?

Tags: c++, строки

### Как правильно поместить строку в массив, разбив предварительно по разделителям?..

Изначально массив строк объявлялся в исходниках:

```
const std::string STRING[] =
{
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
};


.
.
.
DWORD written = 0;
for (auto note : STRING)
{
    WriteFile(file, note.c_str(), note.size(), &written, 0);
}
.
.
.
```

Но сейчас я получаю строку с хоста такого вида:

```
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy|zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

сам затрудняюсь правильно разбить её и поместить в массив STRING[ ],
подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это правильно.

================

Повторюсь.
К примеру имеем две переменные:

```
std::string VERS_ONE = StringGetHost;  // получаем строку с хоста вида "xxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyyyyyy|zzzzzzzzzzzzz"
std::string VERS_TWO[ ] = {
    "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
};
```

Так вот, необходимо привести переменную **VERS_ONE** к полному аналогу **VERS_TWO**, чтобы содержала массив строк (не более 40 строк и не более 100 символов в строке (Unix или Windows)).
Итого что то такое:

```
std::string VERS_ONE(const std::string&& StringGetHost) {
 .
 // Тут обработка
 .
 return vers_one  // полный аналог VERS_TWO
}
```

Поэтому конечно ваши конструкции работают, но они не дают ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: Интересно, мне одному не понятен вопрос?...

Comment: вроде понятно написал:
строку вида "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy|zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" разбить по разделителям "|" и поместить в массив строк const std::string STRING[ ]

Comment: есть большое подозрение, что при данном виде записи в файл (или куда оно там), разделители строк сами не запишутся (если только WriteFile это не делает сам).

Comment: разделители и не должны писаться в файл, они нужны только для разделения на строки общей строки и после удаляются.

Comment: тогда я видимо не совсем понимаю код в вопросе.

Comment: @МатвейУваров, обратите внимание, что размер массива `VERS_TWO[]` неявно (количеством инициализирующих его строк) задается **во время компиляции**. Поэтому *полный аналог* возможен *только в случае*, когда входная строка `VERS_ONE[]` содержит строго определенное количество разделителей. Т.о. вам надо бы придумать (и написать в вопросе), что делать, если  количество "слов" во входной строке 1) меньше 2) больше размера `VERS_TWO[]` (или как-то изменить требования к "полному аналогу" в своей программе)

Comment: `Так вот, необходимо привести переменную VERS_ONE к полному аналогу VERS_TWO, чтобы содержала массив строк` -- вы уверены? В c++ это невозможно, нельзя по ходу выполнения **сменить тип переменной**.

Comment: прочитайте вопрос внимательно... ничего ни на что менять по ходу выполнения не нужно - необходимо полученную строку разбить на подстроки по разделителю и поместить в массив, лучше статический, т.к. заранее известна максимальная  длина подстроки в символах и максимальное количество строк.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, можно использовать `strtok` из C

```
vector<string> v;
string s = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy|zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
for(char * c = strtok(s.data(),"|"); c; c = strtok(nullptr,"|"))
    v.push_back(c);

for(auto t: v) cout << t << endl;
```

можно и руками примерно так:

```
vector<string> v;
string s = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy|zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";

size_t b = 0; // Очередная подстрока
for(size_t e = s.find('|',b); e != s.npos; e = s.find('|',++b))
{
    v.push_back(s.substr(b,e-b));
    b = e;
}
v.push_back(s.substr(b));

for(auto t: v) cout << t << endl;
```

Comment: ...компилятор ругается на цикл for - требуется объявление

Comment: На какой именно? Объявление чего? См. тут - https://ideone.com/AGvj91 - как я могу знать, что именно в вашем компиляторе не так настроено, если вы ничего не пишете?...

Comment: на сколько я помню, безопасно модифицировать содержимое `.data()` можно только с 17 стандарта. Или нет?

Comment: @KoVadim Да, с C++17. И, по большому счету, понятие "безопасно" тут применимо с оговорками. Можно ведь и дописать что-то - это тоже модифицировать.. Но если строку - переменную `s` - потом выбросить нафиг - то готов спорить, что безопасно :) Но паранойи ради готов согласиться, что можно скопировать содержимое строки в какое-то другое место - например, `vector<char>` :) - уж тут точно можно делать такие фокусы...

Comment: мой косяк - все нормально сейчас компилирует... 
но только цикли перебирает бесконечно значения строк и от этого в файл пишется максимально возможное количество повторяющихся одних и тех же строк (https://prnt.sc/rg6gij).
А нужно:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: @Harry я понимаю,когда люди пишут код 11-14 плюсов и забывают об этом сказать. Это ок. Но когда код с 17 с примесью си и спорными моментами - нет, так нельзя.

Comment: @KoVadim, подскажите вашу версию кода, пожалуйста...

Comment: не могу - я вопрос не до конца понимаю.

Comment: @МатвейУваров Вы бы не картинку, а свой код привели, тогда можно было бы смотреть/думать, в чем проблема...

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, вообще-то в 2020 году С++17 - это уже вполне устаканенный стандарт. И явно упоминать о его применении - мне, честно говоря, кажется излишним. Если что не получается скомпилировать etc - ну, тогда можно утрясти этот вопрос...

Comment: @KoVadim - что конкретно вам непонятно

Comment: @Harry, Сделал чтоб было удобней разобраться..
Так код не работает, но нужен именно такой вариант - http://collabedit.com/2jpv5
А так работает, но не пишет строки с новой строки - http://collabedit.com/cey26

Comment: Ну, как вы понимаете, выдранный кусок кода, который не компилируется, никто рассматривать не будет. Или вы даете минимальный, самодостаточный пример, где показываете, что мое решение не работает (а я так понимаю, вы именно на это намекаете), либо полный код, который можно скопировать, напустить на него компилятор и получит работающий пример, с указанием, какие входные данные ему скормить - только тогда можно о чем-то говорить. Тратить на вашу проблему часы времени никто не станет...

Comment: Я понимаю это - время золото... Я подправил суть основного вопроса, возможно сейчас будет понятно.

Comment: По-моему, с единственным отличием - что у меня вектор, а не массив строк (или у вас известно заранее, сколько строк будет в ответе на запрос?). Еще - при чем тут *Т.к. с хоста текст может прилететь как в Unix- так и в Windows-формате*? У вас вроде как поступает строка с `|` в качестве разделителей, и никаких `\n` в ней и близко нет... Словом, ситуация становится все "страньше и страньше" (с)

Comment: Да вы правы, упустил данные по статическому массиву в вопросе:
допускается не более 40 строк и не более 100 символов в строке...
Что касается Windows и Unix  - не обращайте внимания. Это уже отдельный вопрос, вы правы.